# How to add drag and drops attributes to an element in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I created a table in javascript, where now I need to settributes such as ondragstart ondrop etc. I cant find a way to do this

is this as simple as:

```
element.ondrop = function(){

}
```

All I want to know is if this is the right way? or if there is another way to set ondrop ondragstart to an element from javascript.

Comment: Your question is basically, what ways are there to attach event handlers to elements in general, and which ones of those are rather outdated and what is the contemporary way of doing this I should use. And that is something you should be able to research and read up on, without connection to any specific event types.

Comment: You should always attach event listeners instead. `element.addEventListener('drop', function()...)`

Comment: Baao, thanks, why is that? whats the problem? not being an smart ass just want to learn.

Comment: @luke try the search term "addEventListner MDN" if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple ways:

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
```

```css
#div1 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<body>

<p>Drag the W3Schools image into the rectangle:</p>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<img id="drag1" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">

</body>
```

(Credit to https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop)

Or you can do event listeners

```js
/* Event fired on the drag target */
document.addEventListener("dragstart", function(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Started to drag the p element.";
});

/* Events fired on the drop target */
document.addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});

document.addEventListener("drop", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The p element was dropped";
});
```

```css
.droptarget {
    float: left; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 35px;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<body>

<p>This example uses the addEventListener() method to attach "dragstart", "dragover" and "drop" events to the document object.</p>

<p>Drag the p element back and forth between the two rectangles:</p>

<div class="droptarget">
  <p draggable="true" id="dragtarget">Drag me!</p>
</div>

<div class="droptarget"></div>

<p style="clear:both;"><strong>Note:</strong> drag events are not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions or Safari 5.1 and earlier versions.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
```

(Credit to https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_ondrop_addeventlistener)

I just used the w3schools examples since I'm too lazy to make my own lol.

In terms of which is better, I think the second one is more common and accepted, but either should be fine if it's just a personal project or something.

Anyways, tell me if you need any help understanding or anything.